# How can I upload an image from a form without a send button and with auto refresh after upload in Laravel?

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, forms, submit

I tried all the variants I found on the Internet, but not result ..

The route of web.php : `Route::post('profile', 'UserController@update_avatar');`

The form of profile.blade.php :

```
<form id="avatar-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/profile" method="POST">
  <label>Update Profile Image</label>
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{{ $user->name }}">
  <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

The controller :

```
public function update_avatar(Request $request){
        if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
            $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
            $user = Auth::user()->name;
            $filename = $user;
            Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('images/avatars/' . $filename . '.jpg' ) );

            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->avatar = $filename;
            $user->save();
        }

        return redirect('profile')->with('success', 'Your avatar was uploaded with success !');
    }
```

The script with the problem .. :

```
<script>
        $("#avatar").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#avatar-form').serialize(),
                url: "<?php echo url('/profile') ?>",
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                },

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a `change` event:

```
<script>
        $("#avatar").change(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#avatar-form').serialize(),
                url: "<?php echo url('/profile') ?>",
                success:function(data){
                    window.location.href = window.location.href;
                },

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: not does he want to.
but the "url" in the script is ok?

Comment: @IliseiCristian what is echo url('/profile') yielding to you?

Comment: I honestly don't know, I did the script after a tutorial on the net

Comment: Put this into the script as the first operation: alert("<?php echo url('/profile') ?>") and let me know what you see

Comment: Well, nothing happens when I upload the picture, only the name of the uploaded picture appears and so on

Comment: Did you change the function call in the first line from click to change?

Comment: @IliseiCristian type debugger; just before the $.ajax call and let me know what happens. You could also create a JSFiddle.

Comment: @IliseiCristian okay, this means that the variable called $ which is the variable your code expects to be jQuery does not exist. Have you included jQuery into your code?

Comment: yes, i have changed it now with "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" and I do not see that error anymore, but the script still does not work

Comment: there is no error in the console .. I don't know what to say: -? I think the url placed in ajax is not good: -?

Comment: I removed now '' and the link in the url is ok, I don't know what it can be: -?

Comment: @IliseiCristian sorry, edited my answer, please check whether your page reloads.

Comment: in what sense to loading?